# SQL cell equals the sum of a range of cells (same column) when condition is met

Tags: sql, select, subquery

I'm trying to apply the sum of Buy_Ann when it's the same account number. It looks pretty easy but i hasn't been able yet...

```
Date    Account     TX_Ann      COF_Ann     Buy_Ann
Jan     01006243    0.02392433  0.02293156  0.00099277
Feb     01006243    0.02392433  0.02392433  0.00000000
Mar     01006243    0.02392433  0.02392433  0.00000000
Feb     01006491    0.02301613  0.01818841  0.00482772
Mar     01006491    0.02301613  0.02301613  0.00000000
```

My Code is :

```
SELECT 
       [Date]
      ,[Account]
      ,[TX_ann]
      ,[CDF_ann]    
      ,(TX_ann-CDF_ann) as Buy_ann 

 FROM [Table1]
 Order by Account
```

The result i would like to have is : (column Buy_ann)

```
 Date   Account     TX_Ann      COF_Ann     Buy_Ann
 Jan    01006243    0.02392433  0.02293156  0.00099277
 Feb    01006243    0.02392433  0.02392433  0.00099277
 Mar    01006243    0.02392433  0.02392433  0.00099277
 Feb    01006491    0.02301613  0.01818841  0.00482772
 Mar    01006491    0.02301613  0.02301613  0.00482772
```

I tried the following code :

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
       [Date]
      ,[Account]
      ,[TX_ann]
      ,[CDF_ann]    
      ,(Select TOP 1000 Sum(TX_ann-CDF_ann) 
       FROM Table1 Group by Account)) as Buy_ann 
 FROM [Table1]
 Order by Account
```

This is the error message i get : Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I understand what is wrong but i really don't know how to fix it.

To give a little more details, a specific account number will only have one row with a value different from zero in the column Buy_ann (resulting from a one time rate adjustment to the column COF_ann). The problem is that i never know which row it is without looking at the data (and that's why i though about trying to give the value of the sum to all the rows with the same account number). I guess There might be other ways of doing this that are probably more efficient.

Thanks in advance,
Audrey Beaudoin

Answer (score 0):

Almost there! Move `GROUP BY` statement out.
You want to group by `Account` and operate on `Buy_Ann` column.

```
SELECT 
    [Account], 
    SUM((TX_ann-CDF_ann)) AS Buy_Ann 
FROM [Table1] 
GROUP BY [Account]
```

Using `SUM` to aggregate the column that is grouped by `Account` will give you the result.

You can then edit from here with do `ORDER BY` or `TOP1000` etc etc.

---------EDIT------------

In which case your answer is still close. Reason being the summation column returns all the result (like from my solution above), you will have to filter them to be equal to your outer row `Account`.

```
SELECT 
    [Account], 
    [egCol1],
    [egCol2],
    (
        SELECT SUM((TX_ann-CDF_ann)) 
        FROM [Table1] as t1
        GROUP BY [Account]
        HAVING t1.Account = t2.Account
    ) AS Buy_Ann 
FROM [Table1] as t2
```

Comment: @AudreyBeaudoin From the result you are trying to achieve, column Buy_Ann is actually duplicated for the same Account, is there a need for this to show? If you only need the number of record each Account has, you can add count(*) as the 3rd select column.

Comment: Hi @jackc thanks for your answer, the code works but it only keeps the distinct rows

Account     TX_Ann      COF_Ann     Buy_Ann

01006243    0.02392433  0.02392433  0.00099277
01006491    0.02301613  0.01818841  0.00482772

But i really need to keep all the rows even if it's exactly the same.

Comment: yes sorry for the lack of explanation. It's because there are other column i didn't write in the code above because there were too many. I just added the column for the date. I really need all the value of Buy_ann for every date of all the account number.

Comment: @AudreyBeaudoin I have editted the answer, take a look now.

Comment: Or if you only need to group them by date, jainvikram444 answer is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

> Please, try with the query:

```
SELECT [Date]
      ,[Account]
      ,SUM(TX_ann) as TX_ann
      ,SUM(CDF_ann) as CDF_ann
      ,(SUM(TX_ann)-SUM(CDF_ann)) as Buy_ann 
 FROM [Table1]
 GROUP BY Date, Account
 Order by Date, Account
```